# Pass comma-separated arguments to js function

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function calculateAspect(options){
    def = {
        orgw: 0,
        orgh: 0,
        tarw: 0,
        tarh: 0
    };
    o = $.extend(def,options);
    console.log(o);


};    
calculateAspect({orgw:640});
```

And i want to be able to pass it values like following:

```
calculatedAspect(640,480,320)
```

or

```
calculateAspect(200)
```

This may not seem logical, given the function. But i am just curious how to pull it off.

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think you have to pass it the array, or you have to declare the arguments directly.

Comment: What do you want to happen with those numbers you pass a arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) that contains all passed arguments:

```
function calculateAspect(options){
    var argNames = ["orgw","orgh","tarw","tarh"];
    def = {
        orgw: 0,
        orgh: 0,
        tarw: 0,
        tarh: 0
    };
    for (var i=0, n=Math.min(arguments.length, 4); i<n; i++) {
        def[argNames[i]] = arguments[i];
    }
    console.log(o);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make up your own convention for what the parameters should mean, but you could do something like this:

```
function calculateAspect(orgw, orgh, tarw, tarh) {
  var def = { /* ... */ };
  if (arguments.length === 1 && (typeof orgw) === "object") {
    var o = $.extend(def, orgw);
    // ... normal code ...
  }
  else {
    calculateAspect({orgw: orgw, orgh: orgh, tarw: tarw, tarh: tarh});
  }
}
```

maybe.

Comment: No, there's no "built in" way to do it - as far as Javascript is concerned, you can always pass any object (or any value) to any function you want, and it doesn't care much what any of it means. Thus, the language has absolutely no way to guess how you want your object parameters to be interpreted.